# Asserting parentage likelihood based on SNP data

Tags: likelihood, genetics

Let's say I have a population of **N** specimen that I've succesfully genotyped by **M** SNPs. If I know allele frequencies for every SNP, how do I compute likelihood of parental link (e.g. mother-daughter) for two randomly selected individuals that I know the genotypes of?
My guess is that for a single SNP I maybe have to use Bayes' theorem like this (GT is known genotype, ID1 and ID2 signify tested specimen):

$P(ID_1\space is\space mother\space to\space ID_2 |GT_{ID_1}, GT_{ID_2}) = 
\frac{P(GT_{ID_1}, GT_{ID_2} | ID_1 \space is\space mother\space to\space ID_2) *P(ID_1 \space is\space mother\space to\space ID_2)}{P(GT_{ID_1}, GT_{ID_2})}$

We have $P(GT_{ID_1}, GT_{ID_2})$ as the product of frequencies of genotypes infered from allele frequencies.

$P(GT_{ID_1}, GT_{ID_2} | ID_1 \space is\space mother\space to\space ID_2)$ can be inferred as the probability of getting the ID2 genotype from mother of ID1 genotype - can be computed from allele frequencies. What bugs me, though, is the $P(ID_1 \space is\space mother\space to\space ID_2)$ - how can I calculate it?

Also, as a follow-up question, I've only touched upon the situation of only one SNP-based parentage likelihood, so if I want likelihood based on several SNPs I should mulitply the partial likelihood, right?